# functional $F(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-kx}\operatorname{ln}(a(x))dx$ maximization

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima

Good afternoon. I try to find  a function $a(x)>0$ subject to $\int_0^\infty a(x) dx=1$ maximzing the following functional
$$
F(a) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-kx}\operatorname{ln}(a(x))dx.
$$
But I don't know how to do this problem. Because formally we should find a derivate with respect to function. I will be gratefull for hints ideas and literature recomendation.

Comment: You need functional derivatives; see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the probability requirement, we can use Lagrange multipliers. Our Lagrangian is $L:=\int_0^\infty e^{-kx}\ln a dx+\lambda (1-\int_0^\infty a dx)$, so $$0=\frac{\delta L}{\delta a}=e^{-kx}a^{-1}-\lambda.$$Thus $a\propto e^{-kx}$. By unitarity, $a=ke^{-kx}$ with $k>0$. Our stationary point is a maximum because $$\partial_a\frac{\delta L}{\delta a}=-e^{-kx}a^{-2}<0.$$

Comment: Thank you, and how can we find a derivate with respect to a?

Comment: Also, i forget, that a(x) should define a prob. distribution. That is an integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}a(x)=1$

Comment: @MaximKuznetsov I've updated my answer to incorporate that.

Comment: Thank you. And can you recommend the literature, where I can read about this method?

Comment: @MaximKuznetsov Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Functional_derivative & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Proof_in_the_Case_of_Equality_Constraints

Comment: and how can we prove that this is really maximum, not minimum?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

With [Calculus of variations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) we have that:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial a'}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}$$
Where $L$ is the Lagrange function:
$$L(a', a, x)=e^{-kx} \log(a(x))$$
It does not depend on $a'$, so the lhs is zero. So your differential equation for $a$ is:
$$0=e^{-kx} \frac{1}{a}$$
So we can't find an appropriate $a$.
After the edit, the new Lagrange function:
$$L'=L+\lambda(1-a(x))$$
$$L'=e^{-kx} \log(a(x))+\lambda(1-a(x))$$
So the new differential equation is:
$$0=e^{-kx}\frac{1}{a}-\lambda$$
$$\lambda=e^{-kx}\frac{1}{a}$$
$$a(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-kx}$$
Substituting it back to the condition:
$$\lambda=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-kx} \mathrm{d} x$$
$$\lambda=\frac{1}{k}$$
So the function is:
$$a(x)=k e^{-kx}$$